# Passagem de struct pra função dando erro

Tags: c

Estou finalizando uma lista telefônica e o programa compila quase que inteiro, exceto na função com o método de ordenação pros nomes. No trecho do código a seguir, o compilador detecta erro no momento que tento jogar a `struct` para as variáveis temporárias, que farão a troca de posição caso necessário e o mesmo erro ele indica em todos os trechos em que eu tento usar os dados da `struct`. A mensagem de erro diz "expected primary expression before'[' token." E é a mesma mensagem em todos os trechos que tento acessar a `struct`

Trecho da função:

```
   typedef struct agenda{
   char nome[30];
   int numero;
   }agenda;

   void ordenar(void)
   {
    agenda vet;
    int aux=1000, i, j, k, retorno;
    char *str, *str2, *straux;

        arq = fopen("agenda.bin", "a+b");
        for (i = 0; i < aux; i++)
        {
            str = agenda[i].nome;
            for (j = i + 1; j < aux; j++)
            {
                str2 = agenda[j].nome;
                if (strcmp(str, str2) > 0)
                {
                    vet = agenda[i];
                    agenda[i] = agenda[j];
                    agenda[j] = vet;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Qual é a definição da `struct` e qual é a mensagem de erro? Por favor, [edit] a pergunta e adicionar estas informações. E por quê você está acessando as posições de `agenda` quando o nome do objeto é `vet`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editei a pergunta, acho que tá certa agora; e vet é só uma variável do tipo agenda, pra fazer a troca de posição

Comment: Sim, mas dentro da função você utiliza `agenda[i].nome`, como se `agenda` fosse a variável, mas é `vet`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o que faço então pra me referir as variáveis armazenadas no vetor de structs agenda?

Comment: Use o nome da variável `vet`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'agenda' and 'int') dá esse erro; to quase desistindo e tirando a função do programa

Comment: Ok, dê uma boa revisada no seu código. Você abre o arquivo `agenda.bin` e mantém a referência ao mesmo em `arq`, e esse é o único lugar que você utiliza esta variável. Você não deveria ler dados desse arquivo? E onde essa variável foi declarada?

Answer (score 1):

Vejo alguns erros:

1) Você não declarou o ponteiro para arquivo arq:

```
FILE *arq
```

2) agenda é o nome do seu tipo, não uma variável. Assim como não faz sentido você digitar int[i], é o mesmo que digitar agenda[i] como está em:

```
str = agenda[i].nome;
```

3) A sua declaração que é dada por

```
agenda vet;
```

Tem somente um elemento, é como se fosse "int meu_numero;". Não é um vetor e assim você não pode usar "vet[i]", pois vet é uma variável do tipo agenda e não um vetor de tipos agenda.

4) Além de você não declarar o vetor, mesmo se tivesse feito, os seus elementos estão dos bagunçados. Assim, não faz sentido você digitar o código abaixo, que é similar ao seu:

```
void minha_funcao()
{
    int meu_vetor[2];
    int aux;
    if(meu_vetor[0] > meu_vetor[1])
    {
        aux = meu_vetor[0];
        meu_vetor[0] = meu_vetor[1]
        meu_vetor[1] = aux;
    } 
}
```

Neste caso, você está comparando dois valores que não foram declarados de inicio.

Answer (score 0):

O que você gostaria de ter feito era:

```
void ordenar(agenda *vet) {
    /* apenas o código da ordenação aqui, sem leitura de arquivo; essa função deve apenas ordenar o vetor */

    ...
}

agenda *leitura_agendas_arquivo(char *nome_arquivo) {
    /* faça a leitura das estruturas aqui */

    ...
}

agenda *le_ordena_agendas() {
    agenda *vet = leitura_agenda_arquivo("agenda.bin");
    ordena(vet);

    return agenda;
}
```

Não se esqueça de preencher as lacunas!!

Fazendo isso corretamente, todos os quatro apontamentos da [resposta do Carlos Adir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210469/64969) serão sanados.